# Predefined array of HTTP errors for PHP use?

Tags: php, http

I have an `error.php` file attached to `ErrorHandler` that will take the error HTTP status in as a GET variable. Is there an array I can find that has a mapping of status codes to error names and descriptions, or do I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Associative array version**

```
$http_codes = array(
    100 => 'Continue',
    101 => 'Switching Protocols',
    102 => 'Processing',
    103 => 'Checkpoint',
    200 => 'OK',
    201 => 'Created',
    202 => 'Accepted',
    203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
    204 => 'No Content',
    205 => 'Reset Content',
    206 => 'Partial Content',
    207 => 'Multi-Status',
    300 => 'Multiple Choices',
    301 => 'Moved Permanently',
    302 => 'Found',
    303 => 'See Other',
    304 => 'Not Modified',
    305 => 'Use Proxy',
    306 => 'Switch Proxy',
    307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
    400 => 'Bad Request',
    401 => 'Unauthorized',
    402 => 'Payment Required',
    403 => 'Forbidden',
    404 => 'Not Found',
    405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
    406 => 'Not Acceptable',
    407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
    408 => 'Request Timeout',
    409 => 'Conflict',
    410 => 'Gone',
    411 => 'Length Required',
    412 => 'Precondition Failed',
    413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
    414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
    415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
    416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
    417 => 'Expectation Failed',
    418 => 'I\'m a teapot',
    422 => 'Unprocessable Entity',
    423 => 'Locked',
    424 => 'Failed Dependency',
    425 => 'Unordered Collection',
    426 => 'Upgrade Required',
    449 => 'Retry With',
    450 => 'Blocked by Windows Parental Controls',
    500 => 'Internal Server Error',
    501 => 'Not Implemented',
    502 => 'Bad Gateway',
    503 => 'Service Unavailable',
    504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
    505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
    506 => 'Variant Also Negotiates',
    507 => 'Insufficient Storage',
    509 => 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
    510 => 'Not Extended'
);
```

**Normal array version**

```
$http_codes = array(
    array(100, 'Continue'),
    array(101, 'Switching Protocols'),
    array(102, 'Processing'),
    array(103, 'Checkpoint'),
    array(200, 'OK'),
    array(201, 'Created'),
    array(202, 'Accepted'),
    array(203, 'Non-Authoritative Information'),
    array(204, 'No Content'),
    array(205, 'Reset Content'),
    array(206, 'Partial Content'),
    array(207, 'Multi-Status'),
    array(300, 'Multiple Choices'),
    array(301, 'Moved Permanently'),
    array(302, 'Found'),
    array(303, 'See Other'),
    array(304, 'Not Modified'),
    array(305, 'Use Proxy'),
    array(306, 'Switch Proxy'),
    array(307, 'Temporary Redirect'),
    array(400, 'Bad Request'),
    array(401, 'Unauthorized'),
    array(402, 'Payment Required'),
    array(403, 'Forbidden'),
    array(404, 'Not Found'),
    array(405, 'Method Not Allowed'),
    array(406, 'Not Acceptable'),
    array(407, 'Proxy Authentication Required'),
    array(408, 'Request Timeout'),
    array(409, 'Conflict'),
    array(410, 'Gone'),
    array(411, 'Length Required'),
    array(412, 'Precondition Failed'),
    array(413, 'Request Entity Too Large'),
    array(414, 'Request-URI Too Long'),
    array(415, 'Unsupported Media Type'),
    array(416, 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable'),
    array(417, 'Expectation Failed'),
    array(418, 'I\'m a teapot'),
    array(422, 'Unprocessable Entity'),
    array(423, 'Locked'),
    array(424, 'Failed Dependency'),
    array(425, 'Unordered Collection'),
    array(426, 'Upgrade Required'),
    array(449, 'Retry With'),
    array(450, 'Blocked by Windows Parental Controls'),
    array(500, 'Internal Server Error'),
    array(501, 'Not Implemented'),
    array(502, 'Bad Gateway'),
    array(503, 'Service Unavailable'),
    array(504, 'Gateway Timeout'),
    array(505, 'HTTP Version Not Supported'),
    array(506, 'Variant Also Negotiates'),
    array(507, 'Insufficient Storage'),
    array(509, 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded'),
    array(510, 'Not Extended')
);
```

Comment: +1 Though it would be easier to have an associative array (ie. `$http_codes = array(100 => 'Continue', ..., 510 => 'Not Extended');`

Comment: Out of subject but, won't that be easier to read and use this way : `$http_codes = array(100=> 'Continue', 101 => 'Switching Protocols',...);` (I know I may be wrong but I need to know)

Comment: @Svisstack u da real mvp !

Comment: Props for including 418.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a handy object, I've found this one from [here](http://krisjordan.com/php-class-for-http-response-status-codes):

```
<?php

/**
 * StatusCodes provides named constants for
 * HTTP protocol status codes. Written for the
 * Recess Framework (http://www.recessframework.com/)
 *
 * @author Kris Jordan
 * @license MIT
 * @package recess.http
 */
class StatusCodes {

    // [Informational 1xx]
    const HTTP_CONTINUE                        = 100;
    const HTTP_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS             = 101;

    // [Successful 2xx]
    const HTTP_OK                              = 200;
    const HTTP_CREATED                         = 201;
    const HTTP_ACCEPTED                        = 202;
    const HTTP_NONAUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION    = 203;
    const HTTP_NO_CONTENT                      = 204;
    const HTTP_RESET_CONTENT                   = 205;
    const HTTP_PARTIAL_CONTENT                 = 206;

    // [Redirection 3xx]
    const HTTP_MULTIPLE_CHOICES                = 300;
    const HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY               = 301;
    const HTTP_FOUND                           = 302;
    const HTTP_SEE_OTHER                       = 303;
    const HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED                    = 304;
    const HTTP_USE_PROXY                       = 305;
    const HTTP_UNUSED                          = 306;
    const HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT              = 307;

    // [Client Error 4xx]
    const errorCodesBeginAt                    = 400;
    const HTTP_BAD_REQUEST                     = 400;
    const HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED                    = 401;
    const HTTP_PAYMENT_REQUIRED                = 402;
    const HTTP_FORBIDDEN                       = 403;
    const HTTP_NOT_FOUND                       = 404;
    const HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED              = 405;
    const HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE                  = 406;
    const HTTP_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED   = 407;
    const HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT                 = 408;
    const HTTP_CONFLICT                        = 409;
    const HTTP_GONE                            = 410;
    const HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED                 = 411;
    const HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED             = 412;
    const HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE        = 413;
    const HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG            = 414;
    const HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE          = 415;
    const HTTP_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE = 416;
    const HTTP_EXPECTATION_FAILED              = 417;

    // [Server Error 5xx]
    const HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR           = 500;
    const HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED                 = 501;
    const HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY                     = 502;
    const HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE             = 503;
    const HTTP_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT                 = 504;
    const HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED           = 505;

    private static $messages = array(
        // [Informational 1xx]
        100 => '100 Continue',
        101 => '101 Switching Protocols',

        // [Successful 2xx]
        200 => '200 OK',
        201 => '201 Created',
        202 => '202 Accepted',
        203 => '203 Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => '204 No Content',
        205 => '205 Reset Content',
        206 => '206 Partial Content',

        // [Redirection 3xx]
        300 => '300 Multiple Choices',
        301 => '301 Moved Permanently',
        302 => '302 Found',
        303 => '303 See Other',
        304 => '304 Not Modified',
        305 => '305 Use Proxy',
        306 => '306 (Unused)',
        307 => '307 Temporary Redirect',

        // [Client Error 4xx]
        400 => '400 Bad Request',
        401 => '401 Unauthorized',
        402 => '402 Payment Required',
        403 => '403 Forbidden',
        404 => '404 Not Found',
        405 => '405 Method Not Allowed',
        406 => '406 Not Acceptable',
        407 => '407 Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => '408 Request Timeout',
        409 => '409 Conflict',
        410 => '410 Gone',
        411 => '411 Length Required',
        412 => '412 Precondition Failed',
        413 => '413 Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => '414 Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => '415 Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => '416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => '417 Expectation Failed',

        // [Server Error 5xx]
        500 => '500 Internal Server Error',
        501 => '501 Not Implemented',
        502 => '502 Bad Gateway',
        503 => '503 Service Unavailable',
        504 => '504 Gateway Timeout',
        505 => '505 HTTP Version Not Supported'
    );

    public static function httpHeaderFor($code)
    {
        return 'HTTP/1.1 ' . self::$messages[$code];
    }


    public static function getMessageForCode($code)
    {
        return self::$messages[$code];
    }

    public static function isError($code)
    {
        return is_numeric($code) && $code >= self::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;
    }

    public static function canHaveBody($code)
    {
        return
            // True if not in 100s
            ($code < self::HTTP_CONTINUE || $code >= self::HTTP_OK)
            && // and not 204 NO CONTENT
            $code != self::HTTP_NO_CONTENT
            && // and not 304 NOT MODIFIED
            $code != self::HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you webserver is apache i think you can configure errorhandler like `../error.php?errno=404&errstr=Not Found`

Answer (score 0):

If your working on an application that has other [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) dependencies there are a few packages out there that provide all this information for you like [perf/http-status](https://packagist.org/packages/perf/http-status), used like:

```
// Not Found
(new Http11StatusRepository())->get(404)->getReason();
```