# Is there a built in list of http response codes and their DESCRIPTIONS in Laravel or Symfony?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, http-response-codes

Everyone on the internet seems to understand that http response codes have a certain 'description' or 'message'. For example, 404 has the description "Not Found".

So I would expect frameworks like Laravel and Symfony to have a list of such descriptions. Right? But I can't seem to find them.

I'm trying to throw an exception when a cURL request responds with an unacceptable code. I don't have the code messages/descriptions memorized. Neither do I think it's smart to copy/paste/maintain forever an associative array of these values. I just want a framework like Laravel or Symfony to be smart enough to have their own that they manage for everyone. I would expect PHP to have one, but there is no evidence of them having one, and a few people have confirmed as much.

I'm hoping for a function (or maybe a global array?) that works like this:

```
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
    if($responseCode && $responseCode > 399) {
        $message = http_response_code_description($responseCode);
        throw new \Exception("Error $responseCode; $message");//if $responseCode === 404, the exception message would read 'Error 404; Not Found'
    }
```

Since PHP doesn't appear to be helpful in this regard - do Laravel or Symfony have any solutions?

Neither this question... [Predefined array of HTTP errors for PHP use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913960/predefined-array-of-http-errors-for-php-use)

...nor this question... [How to get HTTP status text from HTTP status code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563126/how-to-get-http-status-text-from-http-status-code)

...help in my situation.

I'm not using pure PHP.

I'm not using Guzzle.

I'm not using a request object.

I'm executing a cURL request, in a Laravel project (which includes PHP and Symfony).

I understand that there is no pure PHP solution that automates this. I figured from the beginning that this was likely - which is why I specifically asked if LARAVEL or SYMFONY had a solution in the original question.

Comment: Don't think so, but https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php has a few functions you can use.

Comment: It makes little sense to have texts ready, because they are not bound to be f.e. `Not found` for status `404` - that's the very point of the status. Expect fancy websites to also give you `404 Not found for the last 200 days` or `410 Gone since 2009`, which will help a human reading it much more and still be valid.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense to anyone who doesn't have the meaning of 400+ codes memorized.

Comment: Whoever doesn't look straight to [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#page-49) defining HTTP or at least using the [dedicated Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) but instead relies on 3rd party resources (programming language, framework...) just risks getting incomplete or even wrong data. And has not understood that f.e. `400` is a generic error that should come with a specific text to be helpful to the requester.

Comment: "risks getting incomplete or even wrong data"

99.99999999% of the time, that's an acceptable risk. 
For well-maintained and widely used frameworks like Laravel and Symfony, it's an acceptable risk 100% of the time.

"should come with a specific text to be helpful"
The only specific text that I need in my situation is a basic description because I'm not a computer and I don't have codes 100 through 500 memorized. If more is ever needed, I'm fine with appending more manually.

Feel free to waste your own time with hundreds of lines of manually written and maintained code. I won't.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. 
The difference between PHP and laravel is as significant as the difference between C and C++. So if I ask a question in the context of a php/laravel solution, OBVIOUSLY it's not just for php. It falls through to sumfony/laravel also.

Comment: This question is in the context of PHP only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913960/predefined-array-of-http-errors-for-php-use

This question is in the context of PHP or Guzzle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563126/how-to-get-http-status-text-from-http-status-code

Comment: Mod note: I've cleaned up a conversation about Stack Overflow generally.  If you want to debate how Stack Overflow works as a whole, please take that to [meta].  Otherwise, please stick to this specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited:**
This code will return http error description:
`\Illuminate\Http\Response::$statusTexts["404"]`

Comment: \Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST returns "400". I need something like \Illuminate\Http\Response::HTTP_DESCRIPTIONS[400] that returns "Bad Request"

Comment: Looks like ```public static $statusTexts``` is what I'm looking for in the symfony class that the laravel class extends: \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::$statusTexts[400] returns 'Bad Request'

Comment: can you help me un-flag this as duplicate? (And include  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::$statusTexts in your answer?)